# symbol for mean centering

Tags: data-transformation, centering

I am struggling to write up an equation in the manuscript of a scientific paper, where two of the terms are mean centered around the group mean. In addition, the mean centering is done with excluding the observation the deviance of which from the mean of all other observations is calculated.

How would one summarize such a procedure without too many words? In particular, I am curious if there is a universally acknowledged mathematical symbol for mean centering?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure these is a convention but the phrase leave-one-out is often used about statistics. You could invent leave-one-out means as the term. I would suggest a subscript minus sign to follow the relevant symbol. So $\bar{X}_-$ for a leave one out mean and so forth. As long as you explain it the first time you use it readers will understand.

Comment: But it would depend on the obs left out, maybe something like $\bar{x}_{-i}$?